# Assign a category group to a category field via migration

Tags: plugin-development, migration

I am writing a plugin that sets up Craft in a particular way and have created a category field, but can't figure out how to assign a category group to the field, I have the following:

```
 protected function createCategoriesField() {

        // Get the field group
        $group = (new \craft\db\Query())
            ->select("id")
            ->from("fieldgroups")
            ->where(["name" => "common"])
            ->one();

        // Get the category group
        $catGroup = Craft::$app->categories->getGroupByHandle("categories");


        // Initialize the field
        $field = new \craft\fields\Categories([
            "groupId" => $group["id"],
            "name" => "Categories",
            "handle" => "categories",
            "selectionLabel" => "Select categories",
            "sources" => $catGroup
        ]);

        // Save the field
        return (Craft::$app->getFields()->saveField($field));
    }
```

It seems sources is the correct setting, but it accepts 'source keys' which I'm unfamiliar with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, the format it expects is `'source' => 'group: <group UID>'`

So...

```
    protected function createCategoriesField() {
        // Get the group
        $group = (new \craft\db\Query())
            ->select("id")
            ->from("fieldgroups")
            ->where(["name" => "common"])
            ->one();

        // Get the category group UID
        $catGroup = Craft::$app->categories->getGroupByHandle("categories")->uid;

        // Initialize the field
        $field = new \craft\fields\Categories([
            "groupId" => $group["id"],
            "name" => "Categories",
            "handle" => "categories",
            "selectionLabel" => "Select categories",
            "source" => "group:" . $catGroup
        ]);

        // Save the field
        return (Craft::$app->getFields()->saveField($field));
    }
```

This was, and is, going to be a big help with migrations -> https://github.com/markhuot/craftql/blob/master/src/Console/ToolsController.php

Comment: Does this still work, so far as you are aware? I'm working on a migration and it involves setting the source of a currently existing field to a new category group (still only bound to one group). However, when I try to use `$field->setAttribute(['source' => 'group:'.$groupUid);` and save it, the field's source just sets to 'group:' and then the category group's id, and not the UID, so consequently it fails. Any thoughts on how to get that working?